# How do I convert a single char in string to an int

Tags: c++, string, char, int

Keep in mind, if you choose to answer the question, I am a beginner in the field of programming and may need a bit more explanation than others as to how the solutions work.

Thank you for your help.

**My problem is that I am trying to do computations with parts of a string (consisting only of numbers), but I do not know how to convert an individual char to an int. The string is named "message".**

```
for (int place = 0; place < message.size(); place++)
        {
            if (secondPlace == 0)
            {
                cout << (message[place]) * 100 << endl;
            }
        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean that you want to convert the character `'0'` to the integer `0`, and `'1'` to `1`, et cetera, than the simplest way to do this is probably the following:

```
int number = message[place] - '0';
```

Since the characters for digits are encoded in ascii in ascending numerical order, you can subtract the ascii value of `'0'` from the ascii value of the character in question and get a number equal to the digit.

Comment: @Jive - No, the C (and by extension, C++) standard guarantees that digits are consecutive. Which, in EBCDIC, they are (codes 240 through 250).

Comment: @Chris: not by extension (unless you mean historically). The C++ standard explicitly states that they are consecutive in 2.2/3.

Comment: Grrr at stackoverflow comment police. I tried to remove the comment. Couldn't do it. Tried to edit it. Slapped down again.

Comment: No worries. Rep isn't *that* big a deal. ;)

Comment: Yeah, only thing you need to do is to write cout << (message[place] - '0') * 100 << endl